# Баг с кнопкой "назад" в браузере, нужно нажать на нее два раза чтобы перейти на предыдущую страницу; history, react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Использую React.js / React-router-dom и его хук `useHistory()`;

Кто встречался с таким поведением?

На элементе установлен обработчик события клика:

```
() => history.push("/someRoute")
```

После перехода на эту страницу жму в браузере кнопку "назад" - попадаю на предыдущую страницу, потом снова кликаю по первому элементу - перехожу на `/someRoute`, и снова жму кнопку "назад" и теперь url в браузере сменился на предыдущий, но компонент по этому роуту не отрисовался, требуется нажать на кнопку "назад" еще один раз и все отработает как положено, т.е. сценарий отрабатывает корректно только первый раз, а далее уже нужно кликать два раза, чтобы вернуться на страницу назад.

Нужно это исправить и хочется понять, почему так происходит.

Comment: как выглядит очитска слушателей? используется ли хук `useEffect`? он позволяет в return-блоке указать все, что нужно сбросить

Comment: Есть только хендлер; 
`
const handler= () => {
      history.push("/someRoute");
  };
`
тут сбрасывать нечего

Comment: Добавьте код. В гадалки играть не интересно. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1340969/edit) под вопросом